# Convert from float to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to convert a float number to datetime. For example:

```
float x=70;
```

DateTime should return 1 minute and 10 seconds. (1:30)

Comment: You want a DateTime, or a TimeSpan? A _DateTime_ with a value of 1 minute and 10 seconds indicates a moment in time very long ago.

Comment: @oerkelens I think TimeSpan will also do the trick since I will need to add it to a DateTime later on

Comment: If you want to add it to a DateTime, then you should indeed go for a TimeSpan and not for a DateTime. Adding DateTimes to DateTimes makes no sense, it means adding wednesday to thursday.

Comment: @oerkelens some code would be useful :)

Comment: Well, jeanfrg's answer (constructing TimeSpan from seconds) is all you need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `TimeSpan` to represent a float in time. Keep in mind `TimeSpan` does not accept `float` parameters so you'll need to cast to a `double` type.

```
float x = 70;
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)(new decimal(x)));
```

Then use a reference `DateTime` to "convert" `TimeSpan` to `DateTime`. In this example we're using `epoch`.

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime date = epoch + span;
```

Date would represent the number of seconds (your `float`) from `epoch`.

**Note**: `epoch` ([Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) can be any date (change as needed)

**Demo**: http://rextester.com/QCK29438

Comment: CS0426 The type name 'FromSeconds' does not exist in the @jeanfrg

Comment: My bad, you'll need to convert float to double as FromSeconds does not accept floats as parameters @peter

Comment: CS0176 Member 'TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name

Comment: @peter mine works http://rextester.com/QCK29438. Can you provide the entire context of the code?

Comment: @peter Maybe you tried `TimeSpan TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds...`. That will not work. Never use capitals for local variables anyway :)

Comment: @oerkelens nop... anyway I am using MVC 5 idk if it makes a difference

Comment: @peter it shouldn't can you post a larger portion of your code?

Comment: @peter The error you get means you have are invoking .FromSeconds on an instance of TimeSpan instead of on the type. So doublecheck that in your code or post indeed the exact line of code you use :)

Comment: @jeanfrg oh now I see... anyway what is this epoch thing?

Comment: @jeanfrg Why the decimal constructor? You could just directly typecast a float to decimal, i.e. TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)x). Also there exists an implicit casting from float to double, so TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x) works as well.

Comment: @peter Check the reference in my note. My variable which is named epoch is set to the epoch value, but this depends on your usage. What does you float represent? n seconds from now? or n seconds from epoch? or n seconds from some other date?

Comment: @jeanfrg it represents a constant that I will later have to add to a datetime

Comment: @peter then my variable "epoch" would be your datetime